# Return value from stored procedure to C# function

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I am trying to count how many users is updated and how many users are inserted after I run my stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ADProcTemp]
    @Username varchar(250),
    @DisplayName varchar(70),
    @isEnabled tinyint,
    @PassNevExp tinyint,
    @addedUser int OUTPUT,
    @updatedUser int OUTPUT
AS  
BEGIN   
    SET @addedUser = 0
    SET @updatedUser = 0
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 PrezimeIme FROM [dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD] WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   WHERE NetworkLogin = @Username)
    BEGIN
        IF(@isEnabled = 1 OR @PassNevExp = 1)
             INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD](NetworkLogin, PrezimeIme, Status, PassNevExp)
             VALUES (@Username, @DisplayName, @isEnabled, @PassNevExp)
        SET @addedUser = @addedUser + @@ROWCOUNT;   
        SELECT @addedUser As UkupnoDodanihKorisnika
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD]
        SET Status = @isEnabled,        
            PassNevExp = @PassNevExp
        WHERE NetworkLogin = @Username 
          AND (Status <> @isEnabled) OR (PassNevExp <>@PassNevExp)  
          SET  @updatedUser =  @updatedUser + @@ROWCOUNT; 
          SELECT @updatedUser As UkupnoIzmjenjenihKorisnika
    END  
END
```

Here is my stored procedure and right now I want in my C# code display `@addedUser` and `@updatedUser` variable from stored procedure.

So far I create this

```
public void ExcStrPrc(string Username, string DisplayName, bool isEnable, bool PassNevExp)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ADProcTemp", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username.ToString().Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayName", DisplayName.ToString().Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isEnabled", Convert.ToInt32(isEnable));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassNevExp", Convert.ToInt32(PassNevExp));

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@addedUser", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@updatedUser", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    conn.Open();
    int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();           

    if (k != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Uspjesno izvrseno !");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Ukupno novih korisnika {0}");
    conn.Close();
}
```

Any idea how to display counter from stored procedure to C# function? I added inside my function and right now I didn't get any data in output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBH was a long time ago since I messed around with output parameters, but you add output parameters, but you never check those. The values you require should be in those parameters.
I suggest you try to get those values like (after the execution of course):

```
var addedUserCount = (int)cmd.Parameters["@addedUser"].Value;
```

Or something similar

Comment: I get System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: where did you try to access that parameter?

Comment: After `cmd.Parameters.Add("@updatedUser", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`

Comment: try it after: int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); - you'll need to execute the procedure before you can get results